# How to show last added data in table without reload it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tablecell

I have a tableview and at the time of viewDidLoad there are 20 rows. Now I have a button to add 1 more row data in table. At this time I don't want to reload the table and want to show updated table with last row. Is it possible? If yes then please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:path withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you tell on which table delegate method I'll add this code?

Comment: you can call it anywhere at the time you want to add new row

Comment: Ok, I am adding new row from connectionDidFinishLoading method. Firstly I am reload my table from here but if I am [replace reload table1] through your code then how I'll get the value of path.

Comment: NSIndexPath *path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:your_row inSection:your_section];

Comment: Thanks for your support but in connectionDidFinishLoading how I'll get the your_row and your_section. Please provide a proper place where I can use your code.

Comment: Suppose you are populating your tableview from the data inside your_array (mutable array).... now when you have the data to fill in you last row... add that data to your_array and creat your index path this way NSIndexPath *path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[your_array count] inSection:0];... you can assign section value using some conditon but now i assume you have only one section... then write the above code